# Browser comments out PHP code passed in jQuery append method

Tags: php, jquery, append

I have an ajax functions that appends HTML code to a certain page. I only want to display part of the code if the user does not have a session initialized. The PHP code get's commented out () in the browser while using the append method.
Here's my code:

```
parentEl.append("<div class='forum-reply-thread' id='forum_reply_thread_"+res[i][0]+"'>"+
                                "<p>"+res[i][4]+"</p>"+
                                "<small><a href='profile.php?userid="+res[i][2]+"'>"+res[i][3]+"</a> at "+res[i][6]+"</small>"+
                                "<?php if(isset($_SESSION['ID'])){ ?><button id='forum_reply_button_reply_"+res[i][0]+"'>-></button>"+
                                "<form class='forum-reply-to-reply-form' id='forum_reply_to_reply_form_"+res[i][0]+"'>"+
                                    "<input type='text' id='forum_reply_content_reply_"+res[i][0]+"'>"+
                                    "<button id='forum_submit_reply_to_reply_"+res[i][0]+"'>Reply</button>"+
                                "</form> <?php } ?>"
                                +"</div>");
```

And here is what the browser gets:

```
<!--?php if(isset($_SESSION['ID'])){ ?--> <br>
```

What is going on here? All comments are helpful, even if they do not solve my problem. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can't run PHP through JavaScript like this.

Comment: Is this inline JS on a PHP page prior to output, or an external JS file? In any case, you can't output PHP code via JS after the output.

Comment: You guys have any suggestions to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

I made an ajax call to get session variable I was trying to access. Got the job done.